# What's a word that describes this facial expression?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there such a word? Find this one hard to describe:

[image: cartoon picture of face slightly smiling]

[image: cartoon picture of face slightly smiling]

[image: picture of Weird Al Yankovic's face slightly smiling]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77ZtOG6o6to&feature=youtu.be&t=6s

Edit: Hey guys I hope it's less unclear now with an added video. Please consider reopening.

Comment: In spite of the same style being used for the mouth, I don't find that the two expressions have that much in common. Maybe you should give a brief account of the situation in which the characters are.

Comment: Perhaps *noseless*?

Comment: @Joce it's a restrained shocked / surprised while you're still smiling?

Comment: The raised eyebrows / wide eyes hint strongly at surprise (or the non-verbal communication of '_You don't see _that_ too often!' The mouth is a restrained grin (mild amusement / sense of wellbeing / signalling of friendship). The girl's tilted head hints at a matronly concern. One word? 'Sir Ian Mckellen can convey more by raising one eyebrow than many people can with 1000 words.'

Comment: It is very difficult to answer such a question without knowing what caused these characters to pull such faces.

Comment: I think it's called *obscure*.

Comment: [Happily angry.](http://greatergood.berkeley.edu/article/item/when_getting_angry_makes_you_happy)

Comment: Your update is not asking the same thing as before. Anime faces were scowling.

Comment: @ermanen Huh I don't think so? Literally looks like the same face to me.

Comment: @Harry: In this new photo, the guy is raising the eyebrows and they have a bow shape. Also he is opening the mouth and showing teeth. I can call this face "happily surprised". But in the anime pictures that you put before, the characters had scowling eyebrows and a closed-mouthed smile. There are small details that indicates very different emotions.

Comment: @ermanen fair enough it could be subjective. But I don't think he's happily surprised though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well they both look pretty *wide-eyed* to me.

> **[wide-eyed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wide-eyed)**  [wahyd-ahyd]
>   *adjective*    with the eyes open wide, as in amazement, innocence, or sleeplessness.

<sup>Source: Dictionary.com</sup>

Comment: Excellent probably the best answer so far. I'm not sure if it quite captures the freaky smile though.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this a **[stunned](https://www.google.com/search?q=stunned&oq=stunned&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1626j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)** or **[dazed](https://www.google.com/search?es_sm=93&q=define%20daze&sa=X&ei=GFrhU6OKN4O6oQS58IH4CQ&ved=0CCAQ_SowAA&biw=998&bih=857)** expression.

(I see this all the time in anime, but hardly ever in English media. The closest example I can think of in English is [Al Yankovic's reaction to Fran Drescher in UHF](http://youtu.be/77ZtOG6o6to?t=6s).)

Comment: Oh perfect. Thanks I'll add this to the examples. Stunned or dazed implies a look of confusion but maybe there's no perfect 1-worder for this.

Comment: Yeah, there's probably no perfect single word, at least in English. In long-form, I'd describe it as, "trying to hide shocked disbelief."

Answer (score 0):

I've seen ladies with that look before— *[intense](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intense)*? OOD defines it as

> Having or showing strong feelings or opinions; extremely earnest or serious:
>
> > *an intense young woman, passionate about her art*
> > *a burning and intense look*